# Passing arguments to class as a val

Tags: class, scala, parameters, parameter-passing

When declaring a class in Scala, you can define the parameters as `val`, like this:

```
class MathOperations(val _x: Int, val _y: Int) {
  var x: Int = _x
  var y: Int = _y

  def product = x*y
}
```

But in this case, when I leave out the `val` keyword, an instance of the class behaves exactly the same (as far as I can figure out)

What is the difference between declaring the parameters as I did above, and doing it without `val`, like this:

```
class MathOperations(_x: Int, _y: Int) {
```

Comment: It's duplicated to at least one question ever posted. Here is a brief answer. If you do not define them as `val`, then they do not become members of the class. However, if the class is `case`, every argument becomes a member of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you omit the `val` you will only be able to access `_x` and `_y` within class instance as closure on constructor args (in other words they won't be a members of a class `MathOperations`).

I.e. code like this:

```
val mo = new MathOperations(1, 2)
mo._x
```

... will yield compile error, while if you add `val` it will compile fine.